# Do runes unlock at the same level for all classes in diablo 3?

Tags: diablo-iii

Do runes unlock at the same pre-determined level for all classes?

[image]

Comment: I understand this is a straightforward and almost silly question, but thats ok. I don't want to create a character to find out myself, that is what here is for :p

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. While every class has the same number of abilities, passives, and runes, which skills unlock in which order vary from class to class, with a few exceptions. For instance:

- You will always unlock a skill for a skill slot at the same level you unlock that skill slot
- You will learn your final class ability at level 30.

[Here's an Imgur gallery of the class progression charts.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uj16i.jpg)

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: @Elpezmuerto chart added. You think I should link the images in the post itself?

Comment: might as well. Would save people a click.

Answer (score 0):

No. Character progression is different for each of the game's character classes. The following links will take you to each class's specific rune and ability progression in graph form (Note: This website is seeing a lot of traffic, so it is a tad laggy). I *believe* these are up-to-date.

Wizard - http://www.diablowiki.net/File:Char-prog-wiz.png

Witch Doctor - http://www.diablowiki.net/File:Char-prog-wd.png

Barbarian - http://www.diablowiki.net/File:Char-prog-barb.png

Monk - http://www.diablowiki.net/File:Char-prog-monk.png

Demon Hunter - http://www.diablowiki.net/File:Char-prog-dh.png